# Collection View inside UITableView reuse issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a TableView with a CollectionView inside.
So each Table cell is the delegate of the CollectionView.

The problem is that the collection View reloads on the main thread and the UITableView Cells are being reused.
That causes the collectionView cells to briefly present the labels of previous cells and then fade the changes.
How can I hide those labels when the tableView is initially passed through the return cell ?

The problem happens as collection.reload() is applied after the return cell of the UITableView in cell for row.

Here is a sample of the code.

- *UITableViewCell Code*

```
let collectionDatasource = CollectionDataSource()
```

```
func configureCell(_ object: CustomClass) {

        //Configure Object for tableView
        self.presentedObject = object
        self.nameLabel.text = object.name

        //Set object and items on collection datasource
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let collectionItems = object.collectionItems ?? []
            self.collectionDatasource.object = object
            self.collectionDatasource.items = collectionItems
        }
    }
```

```
class CollectionDataSource: NSObject {
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    var items: [CustomItem] = [] {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let changes = [CustomItem].changes(from: oldValue, to: self.items, identifiedBy: ==, comparedBy: <)
                self.collectionView?.apply(changes: changes)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` itself does its work asynchronously in contrast to `UITableView`. So, even if you will call reload `collectionView` directly in `configureCell` it will update the collection's cells after the table is set up (still can result in the mentioned issue). But you have added the "reload" call into `DispatchQueue.main.async` which makes the things worse.

1. You should skip using `DispatchQueue.main.async` if possible.
2. You should replace collectionView with a new one in `configureCell`. I suggest to add view into the cell of the same size and position as collection view and add collection view in the code. This will guarantee that previous collection view will never appear.

Comment: The reason I want to keep the outlet is because I am using dynamic heights calculated outside the configure cell function. I was trying to "reset" the collection view instead of creating a new one. Would that work ?

Comment: What do you mean? The collectionView should have all constraints specified before equipped with cells. They cannot by dynamic inside UITableView in this case. Is the height of the collection fixed?

Comment: No the height of the collection views is dynamic based on model and height of tableviewcell also dynamic based on state (expandable) and collectionView height.

Comment: Then you need to update collection's view height constraint manually in `UITableViewCell .configureCell()`. So, when collectionView is replaced you need to set all required constraints manually, then table cell with dynamic height will work properly.

Comment: BTW, you can try to use your code but update collectionView not in `configure`, but when the cells became visible. However, you need to remove `DispatchQueue.main.async`, it's not needed.